# What is the safest way to allow a developer to edit 3 Puppet modules?

Tags: linux, permissions, puppet

We have a developer that has to make 3 Puppet modules for an environment. I want him to be able to write his 3 modules.

We currently write our own modules and he is the first person from another department that has to write modules. We use root-access to write/edit our modules, but we do not want to give him root access.

What is the best way to grant him rights to make/edit his 3 modules?
We use the Puppet 3.2.4 and Red Hat Linux 6.4.

Comment: Do your developers make changes to code using root access too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Commit your modules and puppet scripts to a shared Git repository.

Your developers and this new dev can then fork the repository, and make changes, then you can merge the changes back in.

Using root access to edit files without versioning or change control is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

The [official doc](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/bgtm.html#writing_modules_overview) for writing modules is a good place to start.

[Publishing Modules on the Puppet Forge — Documentation — Puppet Labs](https://github.com/puppetlabs/docs-archive/blob/main/puppet/3/modules_publishing.markdown) :

```
puppet generate username-module
$EDITOR Modulefile
puppet module build <MODULE DIRECTORY>
```

[Installing Modules — Documentation — Puppet Labs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/modules_installing.html#modules_installing) :

```
puppet module install --module_repository http://dev-forge.example.com username-module
puppet module upgrade --module_repository http://dev-forge.example.com username-module
```

Comment: This is surely good general advice, but how does it answer the question?

Comment: Create, Test, Share/Publish (Git Push, Pull), Install, Upgrade.